# CSS Floated Elements and overflow: hidden;

Tags: css, css-float, overflow

I noticed some strange behavior the other day and could not find the answer or reason why FF and Chrome behave differently on the following code (jsfiddle):

http://jsfiddle.net/t6g2P/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="one">one</div>
  <div class="two">two</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
 float: left;   
}
.container .one {
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 5px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid deeppink;
}

.container .two {
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 5px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid purple;
}
```

FF: the elements are among each other

Chrome: the elements are floated

Any idea? Would be great to understand that inconsistent behavior. Thx! ;)

Greetz

Comment: it's because your container is floated left with no width given.  Some browsers will expand this until it reaches the max width if you add elements in but others will expand to the width of the widest element within it

Comment: At a first glance I think Chrome is doing it right here. Firefox renders it as if `.two` has a `clear` style: http://jsfiddle.net/t6g2P/1/

Comment: Thx @Pete and Passerby. Yep, that's something I maybe had to point out. There is no width set to the floated container and the elements use width: auto. So the browsers use an different approach to calculate the width. Thx!

Comment: A quick statistical test says that Firefox is the deviate here. IE and all other browsers all behave like Chrome.